# How can I loop over the output of a publisher with Combine?

Tags: swift, combine

I'm working on rewriting my Hacker News reader to use Combine more heavily. I'm have two functions which both return an `AnyPublisher`, one of them get's the ids of a bunch of HN stories from the server and the other one fetches a story by it's id. I'm not sure how I could loop over the results of `fetchStoryIds`, run `fetchStory` with the id and end up with an array of `Story` objects with Combine.

```
import Combine
import Foundation

struct HackerNewsService {
    private var session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    static private var baseURL = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0"

    private func fetchStoryIds(feed: FeedType) -> AnyPublisher<[Int], Error> {
       let url = URL(string: "\(HackerNewsService.baseURL)/\(feed.rawValue.lowercased())stories.json")!

        return session.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .retry(1)
            .map { $0.data }
            .decode(type: [Int].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    private func fetchStory(id: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Story, Error> {
        let url = URL(string: "\(HackerNewsService.baseURL)/item/\(id).json")!

        return session.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { $0.data }
            .decode(type: Story.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Before I started the rewrite, I used this code to loop over the ids and get the stories.

```
func fetchStories(feed: FeedType, completionHandler: @escaping ([Story]?, Error?) -> Void) {
        fetchStoryIds(feed: feed) { (ids, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                return
            }

            guard let ids = ids else {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                return
            }

            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

            var stories = [Story]()

            for id in ids {
                dispatchGroup.enter()

                self.fetchStory(id: id) { (story, error) in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        dispatchGroup.leave()
                        return
                    }

                    guard let story = story else {
                        dispatchGroup.leave()
                        return
                    }

                    stories.append(story)

                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
            }

            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                completionHandler(stories, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I'm not sure how I could loop over the results of fetchStoryIds, run fetchStory with the id and end up with an array of Story objects with Combine." that sounds like `map` to me. And BTW, your old code had a race condition, arising from the unsynchronized access to the `stories` array.

Comment: I think you need to 1) `flatMap` the resultant `Publisher` of `fetchStoryIds`, 2) inside the flat map: a) create an array of all the Ids `map`ped to `fetchStory`, then b) `zip` the collection of `Publisher`s and return that to the `flatMap`.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for the heads up about the race condition. I'll keep an eye out in the future.

Comment: @kezi I got this far then I got confused and errors started popping up. https://www.dropbox.com/s/pq3sm0hphlx3a2z/Screenshot%202019-07-09%2016.10.03.png?dl=0

Comment: That looks fine. Maybe try explicitly stating the return types. The problem might identify itself if the compiler isn't left to inference.

Comment: @kezi I tried explicitly saying that I'm going to return `AnyPublisher<Story, Error>` but I didn't seem to work. https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8rgqxgh0h129ta/Screenshot%202019-07-09%2016.22.46.png?dl=0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmm.. It doesn't look like there is a `Publishers.ZipMany` that accepts a collection of publishers, so instead I merged the stories and collected them instead. Ideally this would collect them in the correct order but I haven't tested that and the documentation is still somewhat sparse across Combine.

```
func fetchStories(feed: FeedType) -> AnyPublisher<[Story], Error> {
    fetchStoryIds(feed: feed)
        .flatMap { ids -> AnyPublisher<[Story], Error> in
            let stories = ids.map { self.fetchStory(id: $0) }
            return Publishers.MergeMany(stories)
                .collect()
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

If you are open to external code this is a gist implementation of ZipMany that will preserve the order:
https://gist.github.com/mwahlig/725fe5e78e385093ba53e6f89028a41c

Although I would think that such a thing would exist in the framework.

Comment: Here is my own implementation of ZipMany, for contrast with the one you've posted: https://gist.github.com/daltonclaybrook/061fa4a8147bfdf69196652285192982